# How to make a pretty Python web app?

Tags: python, ajax, web, web-frameworks

I'm looking for a python web framework that is easy to use and allows me to generate some nice looking user interfaces on the fly. I have not much experience with web development and don't want to spent much time to learn internals.

So far I use cherrypy and mako templating to serve the app. My problem is, it just looks awful. I'd like to have some nice (maybe AJAX?) features available to make the app a little bit more fancy.

My app is a simple search site without any database connection. So I have a main page where the user enters the search string and a result page. In the end it should look like the Goole search, with some hover effects for the results, nice keyboard controls, maybe even something similar like the page preview from Google.

So to achieve this, should I use a different framework or do I need to write the CSS and javascript by hand? What options do I have?

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/CSS-Missing-David-Sawyer-McFarland/dp/0596802447

Comment: As Dhaivat commented, you are describing Design problems. Making a page look better is controlled by CSS, Javascript, HTML, flex and all the other long litany of technologies that change and manipulate the UI itself. They had no direct relation to the underlying webapp.

Comment: You should rather not judge someones experience by the question he asks.
I'm asking for a framework that comes with predefined UI elements and not a book about CSS.

Comment: I was just sharing a book that I have found extremely helpful in learning css, also you said, "I have not much experience with web development."

Comment: @Treebranch your right, I'm sorry for the harsh response, I was just upset about Dhaivat's and Drahkar's unconstructive answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your user interface has nothing to do with the web framework you choose to use.

That said, you might find [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) useful:

> Bootstrap is a toolkit from Twitter designed to kickstart development
> of webapps and sites. It includes base CSS and HTML for typography,
> forms, buttons, tables, grids, navigation, and more.

You might also find this article useful: http://web.archive.org/web/20120418061148/http://jamie-davidson.com/2012/01/resources-to-hack-design/ (original article at: http://jamie-davidson.com/2012/01/resources-to-hack-design/ is no longer available)

Comment: That looks interesting, I'll try it out.

Comment: This works really well, a nice way to create a good look and feel quickly. Even though I was hoping for a solution that would integrate much better with python. With bootstrap there is still a lot of manual work needed to create something maintainable.

Answer (score 3):

> "easy to use"

[Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)

> "generate some nice looking user interfaces on the fly"

[Django!](https://www.djangoproject.com/)

> "don't want to spent much time"

[Django!!](https://www.djangoproject.com/)

---

For javascript, I strongly suggest [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and for some CSS: [Grid 960](http://960.gs/).

Comment: Thanks, I like your enthusiasm about Django. However I was more looking for something on top of that, that would integrate jQuery or similar and some nice CSS. So I'd be able to describe the page in python and have the framework handle the rest.

Answer (score 1):

How about [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) or [Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/)? Maybe [BlueBream](http://bluebream.zope.org/)?  There are so many Python frameworks...  If you're new to dev work, however, choose one in which there's a solid offline local community to lean on...to go to with questions to help get the app built.  (In L.A., it's Django.) But, specifically to your app, my question would be: if you only have essentially just two different page layouts--i.e., the main search page where a user inputs their query, and then X number of dynamically generated pages for the results...and no database--do you really need a whole Python "framework" for that?  You write that you're also looking to dynamically generate "nice looking user interfaces on the fly"...which is a little confusing given the stated scope of your app.

Comment: Well, obviously I did not communicate my problem very well. :-) I'm not at all new to "dev work", I'm only new to web development with python. The "on the fly" was more in respect to minimal development effort than to dynamically generated UI, sorry for that.
However your right there is not much going on so far. That's why I don't want to spent too much time on the UI and that's why I'm looking for something with predefined UI elements. So to say, something like jquery but for the use in python.

Answer (score 0):

[Pyjamas - Python Javascript Compiler, Desktop Widget Set and RIA Web Framework](http://pyjs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I found interesting web2py framework, easy to install, and it has o lot of features as "from the box"

Comment: Can you please add a link where more information about this framework can be found?